# How to handle this XML String

Tags: android, xml, dom, domparser

I figured out how to deal with a 'normal' XML-tree. But I receive the following string from a 3rd party server:

```
<CallOverview>
<Calls Count="2">
<Call CallType="GeoCall" Customer="this account" StartTime="2013-07-22 17:53:22 (UTC)" Destination="+123456789" Duration="00:00:14" Charge="0.00374" CallId="1472453365"/>
<Call CallType="GeoCall" Customer="this account" StartTime="2013-07-22 16:42:45 (UTC)" Destination="+123456789" Duration="00:00:05" Charge="0.00284" CallId="1472377565"/>
</Calls>
<MoreData>False</MoreData>
</CallOverview>
```

I'm retrieving a DOM-element with this method:

```
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
                // return DOM
            return doc;
    }
```

And the results with this method:

```
Element e = (Element) nl.item(i); //nl is a nodelist of parent nodes

    public HashMap<String, String> getResults(Element item) {  
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        NodeList results = item.getElementsByTagName(KEY_RESULT);  

//I run through the node list:
             map.put("RESPONSE", this.getElementValue(results.item(i)));
             ...


return map;
}
```

But when I try the same for this XML, I'm not getting the desired results. 
I want a List of calls with their destination, duration, cost. So basically I want the data between the "":

```
<Call CallType="GeoCall" Customer="this account" StartTime="2013-07-22 17:53:22 (UTC)" Destination="+123456789" Duration="00:00:14" Charge="0.00374" CallId="1472453365"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NodeList results = doc.getElementsByTagName("Call");
for (int i = 0; i < results.getLength(); i++) {
      Element element = (Element) results.item(i);
      String attribute= element.getAttribute("CallType");
      String attribute2= element.getAttribute("Customer");
}
```

You can get attributes with name using `element.getAttribute()` function.